# Array is not changing

Tags: angularjs

So I'm new to angular JS and I am having a problem with editing one object in an array. The liked function below is bring called and the appropriate object is also being passed to it. The loop is even finding the right object and setting its liked value to true. However for some reason when I click the liked button for the second time it still shows the liked value as being false...I'm sure its something super simple.

```
<div class="thelist" data-ng-repeat="b in data| orderBy:choice">
                    <h2>{{ b.from }}</h2>
                    <p>{{b.date}}</p>
                    <img class="full-image" src="{{b.img}}">
                    <p>{{b.content}}</p>
                    <p>{{b.likes}}</p>
                    <button class="tab-item" ng-click="liked({{b}})"></button>

            </div>
```

App.js:

```
ref.on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
                var newPost = snapshot.val();
                $scope.data.push({

                    content: newPost.content,
                    date: newPost.date,
                    from: newPost.from,
                    img: newPost.img,
                    likes: newPost.likes,
                    realdate: newPost.realdate,
                    id: snapshot.key(),
                    liked: false

                });

            });
```

The liked function:

```
        $scope.liked = function (post) {

         if (post.liked == false){
                    console.log("liked has been run");
                    angular.forEach($scope.data, function (object) {

                    if (object.id == post.id) {

                        object.liked = true;

                    }

                });

  //add 1 like on server here        

           }

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not use templating in `ng-click`. Change

```
<button class="tab-item" ng-click="liked({{b}})"></button>
```

to

```
<button class="tab-item" ng-click="liked(b)"></button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew it would be something simple!

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @hege_hegedus's answer, "ng-click" directive  takes an expression (javascript expression with access to $scope variables). Since the since it takes an expression and have complete access to $scope, you can think of

```
<button class="tab-item" ng-click="liked(b)"></button>
```

as

```
<button class="tab-item" ng-click="$scope.liked($scope.b)"></button>
```